# "Согласно Вашего запроса" or "Согласно Вашему запросу"?

Tags: грамматика

"Согласно Вашего запроса" or "Согласно Вашему запросу"?

And if both are correct, what's the difference, if any?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct variant is `Согласно Вашему запросу`.

In the modern Russian language the preposition `согласно` [needs](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_64) the **Dative case**:

> Уже в XIX веке конструкция согласно чего, то есть с родительным падежом, расценивалась как характерная примета официально-деловой, канцелярской речи. В современном русском литературном языке нормативна только конструкция согласно чему, то есть с дательным падежом. Такая конструкция должна употребляться и в официально-деловом стиле.
>
> Правильно: *согласно закону, согласно договору, согласно приказу,
>   согласно указу, согласно распоряжению*.
>
> Already in the 19th century the usage of "согласно" with the Genitive case was considered too official. In the modern Russian language only the Dative case is used with this preposition, even in the official-style texts.
>
> The correct forms: *согласно закону, согласно договору, согласно приказу,
>   согласно указу, согласно распоряжению*.

Answer (score 3):

`согласно вашего запроса` is sometimes used as a bureaucratism (not sure about proper word, we call it канцеляризм). It is NOT correct in common speech, but you can see it in some official responses, or in interviews with officials, and it's kind of OK. But really, don't use it. `согласно` always go with Dative case.